# How to unit-test function that uses global variable?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, powermockito

Suppose you have a class

```
class NeedToTestThisClass{
    private String string1;
    ....
    ....

    private void needToTestThisMethod(){
        if(string1.equals("a")){
            ...
        }
        else{
            ....
            }
   }
}
```

How can I test this method with different string values? The string has no setter, and not included in the constructor. I cannot change the code.
I have powermock.
The question is easy, but can't figure out the way. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerMock to bypass encapsulation

```
@Test
public void test() {
     NeedToTestThisClass tested = new NeedToTestThisClass();
     WhiteBox.setInternalState(tested,"string1", "someValue");
     Whitebox.invokeMethod(tested, "needToTestThisMethod");
     //here verify something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, these type of scenarios are tested by testing the public method that actually uses these kinds private methods. In general try to test the flow that mutates the string1 variable and in-turn your private methods get touched by the tests.

Comment: it is much more complicated than my example. the only initiation of the String - is server response. And I need to test it without asking server.